# Search JSON file from python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to search for a variable in a JSON file.

**Current JSON file (devices.json) is:**

```
{
  "NYC": {
    "Floor1": [
      {
        "name": "server1",
        "ip": "1.1.1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "server2",
        "ip": "1.1.1.2"
      }
    ],
    "Floor2": [
      ...
    ],
    "sitenum": 1
  },
  "Boston": {
    ...
    "sitenum": 2
  }
  ...
}
```

Two questions:

1. I am new to JSON, so is this formatted correctly for
   lists/dictionaries?
2. I'd like to preform a python query to display Floor(s){name, ip} for sitenum (x)

Current Python file is

```
import json

with open('devices.json') as jsonfile:
  data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Thanks!

Comment: "is this formatted correctly"...you can use a tool such as https://jsonlint.com/ to validate JSON strings.

Comment: Your JSON is missing commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this python script will return the floor details as a list of json values for a given `sitenum` and `floor`.

```
import json

def get_floor_details(sitenum, floor, data):
    for k,v in data.items():
        if v['sitenum'] == sitenum:
            return(v[floor])


with open('sample.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    sitenum = 1
    floor = 'Floor1'
    floor_details = get_floor_details(sitenum, floor, data)
    print(floor_details)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'server1', 'ip': '1.1.1.1'}, {'name': 'server2', 'ip': '1.1.1.2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findFloor(site_num_val, data):
    return_val = {}
    for each_loc in data:
        if site_num_val == each_loc["sitenum"]:
           return_val = data[each_loc].copy()
           del return_val["sitenum"]
           break
    else:
        print "sitenum not found"
    return return_val
```

I hope this solves your problem in trying to get the information.